# How can I store my captured picture on my server

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova

I am using Phonegap to create an app specific for Android, Ios and Windows phone. With this I am using the Camera API to capture pictures on your phone. These are currently not being stored and will be deleted on reopen. Therefore i'd like to access my server to store the pictures (like in .jpeg format for example). This via JavaScript / HTML. How can i create this file and store it?

var pictureSource;   // picture source
    var destinationType; // sets the format of returned value

```
// Wait for device API libraries to load
//
document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);

// device APIs are available
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    pictureSource=navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
    destinationType=navigator.camera.DestinationType;
}

// Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
//
function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) {
  // Uncomment to view the base64-encoded image data
  // console.log(imageData);

  // Get image handle
  //
  var smallImage = document.getElementById('smallImage');

  // Unhide image elements
  //
  smallImage.style.display = 'block';

  // Show the captured photo
  // The in-line CSS rules are used to resize the image
  //
  smallImage.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
}

// Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
//
function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {
  // Uncomment to view the image file URI
  // console.log(imageURI);

  // Get image handle
  //
  var largeImage = document.getElementById('largeImage');

  // Unhide image elements
  //
  largeImage.style.display = 'block';

  // Show the captured photo
  // The in-line CSS rules are used to resize the image
  //
  largeImage.src = imageURI;
}

// A button will call this function
//
function capturePhoto() {
  // Take picture using device camera and retrieve image as base64-encoded string
  navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
    destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL });
}

// A button will call this function
//
function capturePhotoEdit() {
  // Take picture using device camera, allow edit, and retrieve image as base64-encoded string
  navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 20, allowEdit: true,
    destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL });
}

// A button will call this function
//
function getPhoto(source) {
  // Retrieve image file location from specified source
  navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
    destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
    sourceType: source });
}

// Called if something bad happens.
//
function onFail(message) {
  alert('Failed because: ' + message);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can get the FILE_URI then upload it to your server using php as example like the following:

**Phonegap code:**

```
function uploadPhoto(imageURI) {
            var options = new FileUploadOptions();
            options.fileKey="file";
            options.fileName=imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
            options.mimeType="image/jpeg";

            var params = new Object();
            params.value1 = "test";
            params.value2 = "param";

            options.params = params;
            options.chunkedMode = false;

            var ft = new FileTransfer();
            ft.upload(imageURI, "http://yourdomain.com/upload.php", win, fail, options);
        }

        navigator.camera.getPicture(uploadPhoto, function(message) {
       alert('get picture failed');
    },{
            quality: 50, 
            destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
            sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
        }
            );
```

**PHP Code (upload.php):**

```
<?php
print_r($_FILES);
$new_image_name = "namethisimage.jpg";
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "/srv/www/upload/".$new_image_name);
?>
```

Comment: While this works, I'm not sure I'd recommend it. The docs recommend you use files for camera results, not base64 strings, as these strings can be *huge* and have an impact on memory. If you use a file, you can easily do the same POST using the FileTransfer API.

Comment: How exactly can i put this picture in a file to post this with the FileTransfer API?

Comment: @RaymondCamden you are right, I updated my answer to use FILE_URI

Comment: It is currently not working properly for me. It doesnt seem to be sending the picture to the server. Could you give me more information about sending it / receiving and maybe where i could find the errors that help solving this problem?

Comment: @patrick: Can you add some logs from your server and phonegap app to understand the issue?

Comment: @patrick make sure that you update your access policy in config.xml file